# Removing smptd smtpq service in OpenBSD bare installation

Tags: package-management, services, openbsd

In a recent installation of OpenBSD, I noticed that the `smtpd` daemon is present.

```
gelima# ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM   VSZ   RSS TT  STAT   STARTED       TIME COMMAND
[...]
root     90899  0.0  0.0  1720  2236 ??  Ip     10:26PM    0:00.02 /usr/sbin/smtpd
_smtpd   46484  0.0  0.0  1452  3244 ??  Ipc    10:26PM    0:00.02 smtpd: crypto (smtpd)
_smtpd   24355  0.0  0.0  1656  3484 ??  Ipc    10:26PM    0:00.03 smtpd: control (smtpd)
_smtpd    2198  0.0  0.0  1524  3356 ??  Ip     10:26PM    0:00.04 smtpd: lookup (smtpd)
_smtpd   10223  0.0  0.1  1932  4700 ??  Ipc    10:26PM    0:00.05 smtpd: dispatcher (smtpd)
_smtpq   87986  0.0  0.0  1652  3464 ??  Ipc    10:26PM    0:00.03 smtpd: queue (smtpd)
_smtpd    9288  0.0  0.0  1456  3304 ??  Ipc    10:26PM    0:00.04 smtpd: scheduler (smtpd)
_sndiop  14528  0.0  0.0  2656   996 ??  IpU    10:26PM    0:00.00 sndiod: helper (sndiod)
```

How can I find the package which `/usr/sbin/smtpd` belongs to and remove it from system. I don't want to disable `smtpd` service from the system, I want to **delete** it.

I see that it is not available in binary packages.

```
# pkg_info -mz
htop--
nginx--
pkglocatedb--
quirks--
vim--no_x11
```

So where is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`smtpd` is part of the OpenBSD base install, as is a number of other daemons (`nsd`, `unbound`, `httpd`, `relayd`, `dhcpd`, etc).  It is an integral part of the system and it is not meant to be removed.  That's why it is useless to search for it in packages.

It can, as all other daemons, be *disabled* (a simple "rcctl disable smtpd" suffices), but this means you will not receive any of the automatic emails related with the system's administration, namely the alerts when a `cron` job fails, or the results of the `daily` and `weekly` scripts.  The latter include things like lists of changed files (see `man changelist`), changes to `setuid` binaries, etc.  See the `man` pages for `daily` and `weekly` to see all you'll be missing out on.  These mails are delivered locally, to `root`'s `mbox`, unless you change `/etc/mail/aliases`.

Note that by default, `smtpd` only listens on `lo0`, so it does not accept any messages from other hosts.  It only accepts messages from local users and either delivers them to local `mbox` accounts, or relays them to the destination domain's MTAs.  If you want to keep local users from sending mail to external domains, you can simply remove the appropriate rule on `/etc/mail/smtpd.conf`.  This won't stop the users from sending to local addresses though, but you can do some filtering (e.g. by sender or by destination address).

You don't specify why you want to actually **delete** `smtpd`, so I can only guess, and I find it hard to find a reason to do so.  You can simply disable it, as stated above.  It can only be started by `root` (and then runs with extensive privilege separation) so if you are worried that someone might maliciously start it, you are missing the forest for the trees.  For someone to be able to start `smtpd` they must have `root` access, and if that is the case, you have much bigger problems than a mailer daemon.  By disabling it, the system won't be able to send messages like the aforementioned `cron` outputs and the like, so don't be surprised if things break.

If you *still* want to do it, you can just `rm` the binary, of course (just run `rcctl disable smtpd` first, otherwise you'll get an error everytime you boot the system).  Just don't go complaining about some pain and a bullet-shaped hole on your foot, afterwards.